# Spring SAML , ADFS with Angular JS

Tags: adfs, spring-saml

we have configured Angularjs + spring saml with ADFS in our application and it runs fine. but sometimes when i close the browser and reopen its not redirecting to either login page or user selection page. 
Angular tables also not loading if this scenario happens. if i refresh it goes to ADFS user selection page and returns to application and there after works fine.

Any help here please. Thanks in advance.

Edit: When we checked in the developer console below error was thrown.

Refused to execute script from 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/e4e1abd9-eac7-4a71-ab52-da5c998aa7ba/saml2?SAMLRequest=*** because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

*** --> SAML Request.

When this happens few of our JS files were not loading into browser.

Comment: Put some code/error  else it would not be possible to help.